# Nested json containing list of json-strings to dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `json` string that I would like to get into a dataframe:

```
jsonstr = {
  "id": "12345",
  "ename": "A4.txt",
  "Zoom1": {
    "Zoom1_res": [
      {
        "code": "A1",
        "x": 3211,
        "y": 677,
        "part": "11",
        "lace": "29",
        "name": "COVER"
      },
      {
        "code": "A4",
        "x": 3492,
        "y": 1109,
        "part": "10",
        "lace": "19",
        "name": "ARMOUR"
      }
    ]
  },
  "iSize": {
    "width": 4608,
    "height": 3456
  },
  "Action": {
    "AA": {
      "detect": [
        {
          "class": "aa",
          "prob": 0.92,
          "Box": {
            "x0": 4406,
            "y0": 670,
            "x1": 4558,
            "y1": 760
          }
        },
        {
          "class": "aa",
          "prob": 0.92,
          "Box": {
            "x0": 3762,
            "y0": 655,
            "x1": 3913,
            "y1": 747
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `json_read` in the following way:

```
df =pd.read_json(jsonstr)
```

returns

```
 id   ename                                              Zoom1  \
Zoom1_res  12345  A4.txt  [{'code': 'A1', 'x': 3211, 'y': 677, 'part': '...   
width      12345  A4.txt                                                NaN   
height     12345  A4.txt                                                NaN   
AA         12345  A4.txt                                                NaN   

            iSize                                             Action  
Zoom1_res     NaN                                                NaN  
width      4608.0                                                NaN  
height     3456.0                                                NaN  
AA            NaN  {'detect': [{'class': 'aa', 'prob': 0.92, 'Box...
```

and

```
pd.json_normalize(df['Action'])
```

returns the error

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values'
```

So, I thought that applying

```
from ast import literal_eval

pd.json_normalize(df['Action'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)["detect"]).explode())
```

might solve the problem, but there are `nan` in that column, so even this doesn't work.

What I actually want is:

In the best of all worlds: `id, ename, code, x, y, x0, y0, x1, y1`

All other data is of no worth to me.

Grateful for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your JSON is nested on multiple levels,

#### 1. Creting sub dataframes

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr, record_path=['Action','AA','detect'],  meta=['id','ename'])
df2 = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr, record_path=['Zoom1','Zoom1_res'],  meta=['id','ename'])
```

#### 2. Shifting Data to NaN

As per my understanding, the gBOX and BOX are the same attributes, so you can merge them in this way, well you can play around with these and get the required data

```
df3 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
df3.columns = ['class','prob','x0','y0','x1','y1','id','ename']
```

#### 3. Get required columns as per your data

```
df4 = pd.merge(df3, df2, on=['id','ename'])
df4 = df4.iloc[:,[6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: This is really really nice! One comment though: ```, left_index=True, right_index=True``` doesn't work for me. Thank you!